# Website Listing Commonly Used Ruby Gems, Including Alternatives

Tags: ruby

I know that I've seen this site before, but cannot remember it for the life of me. Basically, it is a listing of commonly used gems, like XML parsing or ORM libraries. For the ORM case, it lists ActiveRecord, DataMapper, and the like, stating the advantages and disadvantages of each. Does anyone know what this site is? I've googled and have not been able to find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have ruby-toolbox for that http://www.ruby-toolbox.com

You know only information about their activity on github. But it's interesting.